# Meteor.setTimeout() inside in Meteor.loginWithPassword()

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, angularjs-ng-disabled

I need help.
My code is in a login.
When the user click in `login`: I put a button disable to avoid that the user do click many times when the system is working, waiting for a answer

My code works fine, but I put a loader class when the user click in button login.

When the user put the password and is acepted, the system send us to the next view. This works fine, but...
The problem is:
When the user put a invalid pasword `this.loadingActive = true;` dont change..  the button remain with the spin active forever. I mean something happend that the variable `loadingActive`  dont change to `true`

**my html**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block"
        ng-class="{'disabled': login.loadingActive === false}"
        ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid || login.loadingActive === false"
        ng-click="login.login()">
    <span ng-hide="login.loadingActive" class="fa fa-refresh animacion-cargando"></span>
    <span ng-hide="login.loadingActive">loading...</span>
    <span ng-show="login.loadingActive">Login</span>
</button>
```

**This is my js file**

```
login() {
    this.loadingActive = false;
    this.error = '';
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(this.credentials.email.toLowerCase(), this.credentials.password,
        this.$bindToContext((err) => {
            Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
                if (err) {
                    this.loadingActive = true;
                    this.error = err;
                } else {
                    this.loadingActive = true;
                    this.$state.go('app.pageOne');
                }
            }, 1000);
        })
    );
}
```

Why when I put a Meteor.setTimeout inside a  Meteor.loginWithPassword happen this?
any ideas?

**thanks!**

Comment: This is not a good pattern for rate-limiting. Look at [DDPRateLimiter](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#ddpratelimiter). Besides that I think the problem is that `this` inside the `setTimeout` is not the same `this` as in the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

I see you wrap the callback inside a `this.$bindToContext`. Not sure what it does but my guess is that it changes the context (`this`) the callback function so that `this.loadingActive = true` has no effect.

To fix this you could use a reference variable:

```
login() {
  const self = this;
  // ...
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(
    self.credentials.email.toLowerCase(),
    self.credentials.password,
    self.$bindToContext((err) => {
      Meteor.setTimeout(() => {
        // ...
        self.loadingActive = true;
      }, 1000);
    }
  ));
}
```